# ERROR : Location of the symbol related to previous error in C# code

Tags: c#, function, class, object, oop

```
using System;

public class Student 
{
  string name;         
  int age;   
  
  public string inputName()    
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name :"); 
    string name= Console.Readline();
    return name;
  }
  
  public void showName(string name){
      Console.WriteLine(name);
  }
  
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Student myObj = new Student();
    string name=myObj.inputName();
    myObj.showName(name);
  }
}
```

Unable to understand what is incorrect in the above code. I want to take name and age of student as input through the method in C# class and then print the same using another method. I was thinking I will create an object in main() and call the getters and setters function from main.
Initially, I guessed that the Console.Readline() was causing the issue and therefore tried to look if I was forgetting any library to import for Readline() but could not successfully get the reason behind this reason.
I am totally new to c#, kindly help.
NOTE: I am using an online compiler for my above C# code so if this error is specific to that case kindly let me know that as well.

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks functionally correct to me, even though you are hiding the class member `name` and it could be written better,

Comment: How did `static void Main()` end up inside your `Student` class? Did you rename `class Program` to `class Student`? Give your `Student` class its own file and add `Console.ReadKey()` as the last line in `Main`, so the program won't exit immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main method must not be inside the Student class

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
}
public class Student 
{

}
```

Following errors:

```
Student myObj = new Student(); // is correct, creates an instance
string name=myObj.inputName(); // semantic error
myObj.showName(name);
```

Here you declare a new string and assign it the input name function. The inputName() in it of itself is correct, but you probably meant to have the name assigned to the object field `string name;`

So the following

```
public string inputName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name :");
        string name = Console.Readline();
        return name;
    }
```

need to be

```
public void inputName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name :");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        this.name = name;
    }
```

The return type is changed from string to void, as it does not need to return a value. this.name = name assigns the input to the name field on the object.

The function

```
public void showName(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

is also a semantic error. There are no functional errors, but you do not need a parameter. The (string name) is the input of the function, if you want to show the current name of the object this is where you use a return type without any parameters.

```
public string showName()
    {
        return name;
    }
```

So the final revision would be

```
public class Program
{

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student myObj = new Student();
    myObj.inputName();
    Console.WriteLine(myObj.showName());
}

public class Student
{
    string name;
    int age;
    public void inputName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name :");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string showName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this solved my problem and gave me a basic idea of where to start. Thank you so much.